# Why does OLEDB (or Access?) rewrite WHERE clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

I'm facing a strange situation where `OledbDataAdapter` rearranges the WHERE clause of my query, thus shuffling all parameters. In addition, it doesn't recognize one of the parameters used in the query. Here's how it goes:

A simple table with 4 columns (and infinite rows :)):

```
Name       varchar(50)
Category   varchar(20)  //One of around 15-20 possible values
YR         int          //Year
Period     int          //Month
```

User will query this table using Year, Month and a comma-separated list of categories that he's interested in. Since .NET doesn't support multi-valued parameters through `IN` operator, what I do is to accept the list of categories as comma-separated list and then prepend and append a comma to this list within the query and use built-in `INSTR()` function to filter results for desired categories. User can also supply an empty string for categories filter in which case query will need to return all results (i.e. no filter on categories).

Therefore my query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table1] WHERE
       YR = ? AND 
       Period = ? AND 
       (LTRIM(RTRIM(?)) = '' OR INSTR(1, ?, ',' + Category + ',') > 0)
```

This worked with MDBs in the past. But recently I tried it against an ACCDB. The first thing I noted is that when I try to run the query in OledbDataAdapter wizard, Visual Studio rewrites it as:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table1] WHERE
       (YR = ? AND Period = ? AND LTRIM(RTRIM(?)) = '') OR 
       (YR = ? AND Period = ? AND INSTR(1, ?, ',' + Category + ',') > 0)
```

In other words, it has rearranged the condition `A AND B AND (C OR D)` as `(A AND B AND C) OR (A AND B AND D)`.

This would have been fine with me, but the additional problem is that this changes the number of parameters from 4 to 6; the query therefore doesn't return any results even when it should. Moreover, it doesn't recognize that last parameter (the question mark within INSTR function) at all.

So my questions are:

1. Who is rewriting the query (`OledbDataAdapter`, Access query parser or something else)?
2. Why is it doing so? Optimization? Apparently my version of the WHERE clause is more efficient.
3. Why doesn't it see the last parameter?
4. How to fix/workaround this issue? (plz do not suggest using 2 separate queries for it).

Comment: Yours is in conjunctive normal form and it is being rewritten to disjunctive normal form. I spend a lot of my time rewriting search conditions in DNF to CNF because I find them easier to understand, to covert to database constraints, etc. I'm surprised the optimizer would do the opposite; not surprised it performs worse; surprised the optimizer would make it worse!

Comment: ...though I can see some logic: in DNF only one disjunction needs to false -- I mean, not true (3VL!) for the whole `WHERE` clause to be false (short circuit); with CNF all must be true.

Comment: @onedaywhen: hmm... I probably see what you mean. How to solve the problem at hand? Why wouldn't it see the parameter used inside the function?

Comment: Suggestion: create a stored proc in Access containing 20 named parameters (5 of which optional), then executing the proc on the .NET side passing 15-20 arguments.

Comment: FWIW here's a demo of the CNF to DNF rewrite (click the 'Text notation buttons'): [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DNF+P+AND+Q+AND+(R+OR+S)&dataset=)

Comment: @onedaywhen: Unfortunately I do not have control over the Access database. Read-only access allows my application to query it, nothing else.

Comment: I haven't used Access in a while but IIRC you can use named parameters in an ad hoc query e.g. `PARAMETERS arg_YR INT; SELECT DISTINCT 'true' FROM Table1 WHERE YR = arg_YR;` - worth a try?

Comment: @onedaywhen: Not 100% sure about Access, but at least `OledbCommand` [doesn't support named parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx), which is exactly what I'm using to query the database.

Comment: I see. Well how about changing **your** text to be what the provider would otherwise want to rewrite it to, then pass 6 parameters (two of which will be duplicated of course) in the now required order?

Comment: @onedaywhen: That's what I was ultimately ready to do. But even that is not an option. As I mentioned in the question, `OledbCommand` does not recognize the parameter used inside `INSTR()` function. Disappointed I have now moved this filtering stuff to client side. Problem at hand solved, but I'm still interested in knowing answers to the above questions.

Comment: Just wondering, what if you rewrite your where as ((yr =? And period=? And ltrim(rtrim(?)) = '') OR (INSTR...))?

Comment: @krishKM: You're changing `A AND B AND (C OR D)` to `(A AND B AND C) OR D`, which are obviously not equivalent, so even if that works, that ain't going to help.

Comment: No, the rewrite is `A AND B AND (C OR D)` `<=>` `(A AND B AND C) OR (A AND B AND D)`.Look at the wolframalpha link I posted above, specifically the minimal forms (click the 'Text notation' button).

Comment: Is it just the `INSTR` expression that is causing problems e.g. try a query with just one parameter inside `INSTR`: does it get seen? If it does then maybe there's a chance you can trick it e.g. `SELECT * FROM T WHERE A AND B AND C UNION SELECT * FROM T WHERE A AND B AND D;`

Comment: "Disappointed I have now moved this filtering stuff to client side" - you have access to the server side but not the database?! Have you tried? e.g. `CREATE PROCEDURE GetT (arg_YR INT) AS SELECT DISTINCT 'true' FROM Table1 WHERE YR = arg_YR;` and then `EXECUTE GetT ?;`

Comment: @onedaywhen: 1. My previous comment was directed at krishKM, not you. 2. On deployment machine, I'll get read-only access to the database, so creating a procedure is not an option. 3. I'll check out what happens if I use `INSTR()` alone. I'll post my findings here once I'm done. Thanks for being with me for so long.